# MySQL trying to imporrt file.sql but nothing happens

Tags: mysql, import

I am trying to import a database with a `.sql` file but when I'm trying it nothing happens:

```
user:~$ sudo mysql -u root -p database_name < Documents/Project/Projects-db/file.sql
Enter password: 
user:~$
```

Comment: "Nothing happens" as in "there isn't any data inside my db after the command"?

Comment: @Cynical That is true

Comment: Have you checked the log? What's the content of `file.sql`? What are you trying to do? Does it work if you execute the statements directly from mysql client instead of redirecting it from the file?

Comment: I just checked the `.sql` file and for some reason it was empty...